# cygwin /dev/sd* disk association to hard drive

Tags: linux, windows, cygwin, hard-drive

Under cygwin on Windows 7, how would I certainly determine the hard drive that some path `/dev/sd*`  corresponds in Windows?

For example, given cygwin path `/dev/sdc`, which Windows letter drive does it correspond, `C:\`, `D:\`, etc.?

The following don't appear available within cygwin; tool `lshw`, tool `parted`, path `/dev/disk/...`.

Comment: Does `sudo fdisk -l` work?

Comment: I forgot about `fdisk`!  Thanks @ifconfig .

Comment: Did it work for you, @JamesThomasMoon1979? Does it show what you want it to?

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on  http://superuser.com or another StackExchange site. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are asking how to map Windows Disk to devices:

```
$ cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name   win-mounts

    8     0 175825944 sda
    8     1 175824896 sda1   C:\
    8    16 1953514582 sdb
    8    17 1953512448 sdb1   E:\
```